# Need help with unit converter app getting uipicker to call a function

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

something is going haw ire in tis bit of code

```
      - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)
      thePickerView didSelectRow:
     (NSInteger)rowinComponent:(NSInteger)component {
      if ( row ==1) {

    -(IBAction)presstoconvert{

    float number1 = ([initamount.text floatValue ]);
    float answer = number1 *12;
    result.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f", answer];
    }
}

else ( row == 2);{
    float number1 = ([initamount.text floatValue ]);
    float answer = number1 /12;
    result.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%2.f", answer];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why have you defined an `pressToConvert` inside `didSelectRow:`? Just remove -`(IBAction)presstoconvert{` & the corresponding `}` & you should be good.

Otherwise, you could move `pressToConvert` outside this method body and call it from here.

Comment: thank you btw, the only reason why i thought what i am showing is because i have a button that when you press it it will so the conversion. I would like the ui picker to select the conversion and then when the user inputs the amount they want to convert they would hit the button. idk